# Can you have an empty string for a Python enum attribute?

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

I'd really like to use Python enum types for this model I'm working on. The problem is one of the potential values from the data provider is an empty string.

Given this model...

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum

class Events(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'events'
        ...
        restriction_code = Column(Enum(RestrictionCode))
        ...
```

...one of the enum types would have an "empty string" as an attribute like this...

```
from enum import Enum

class RestrictionCode(Enum):
    A = 'A Description'
    B = 'B Description'
    C = 'C Description'
    D = 'D Description'
    '' = 'No Restriction'
```

The above produces the not surprising: `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`. Is this even possible or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, each Enum member must have a name.

The intended way to use Enums in this scenario would be to have the value of the member be the value stored in the database, so your Enum should look like:

```
class RestrictionCode(Enum):
    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    C = 'C'
    D = 'D'
    NONE = ''
```

If you want a description as well, you'll need to design your own Enum -- but it's not hard:

```
class DescriptiveEnum(Enum):
    #
    def __new__(cls, value, description):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member.description = description
        return member
```

Then your `RestrictionCode` will look like:

```
class RestrictionCode(DescriptiveEnum):
    A = 'A', 'A description'
    B = 'B', 'B description'
    C = 'C', 'C description'
    D = 'D', 'D description'
    NONE = '', 'No restriction'
```